# Magento Error: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1065 Query was empty

Tags: magento, authentication

Upon logging into the admin section of the magento cart I receive the following error:

> SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1065 Query was
>   empty

Thank you in advance for any suggestions or solutions, I am unable to work in the back end of the cart until I resolve this.

Here is the mysql general log output:

```
46 Query    SET SQL_MODE=''
46 Query    SET NAMES utf8
46 Query    SHOW TABLE STATUS LIKE 'core_resource'
46 Query    SELECT `core_resource`.* FROM `core_resource`
46 Query    SELECT `index_process`.`indexer_code` FROM `index_process`
46 Query    SELECT `core_website`.`website_id`, `core_website`.`code`, `core_website`.`name` FROM `core_website`
46 Query    SELECT `core_store`.`store_id`, `core_store`.`code`, `core_store`.`name`, `core_store`.`website_id` FROM `core_store` ORDER BY `sort_order` ASC
46 Query    SELECT `core_config_data`.`scope`, `core_config_data`.`scope_id`, `core_config_data`.`path`, `core_config_data`.`value` FROM `core_config_data`
46 Query    SELECT `main_table`.* FROM `core_store` AS `main_table` ORDER BY CASE WHEN main_table.store_id = 0 THEN 0 ELSE 1 END ASC, main_table.sort_order ASC, main_table.name ASC
46 Query    SELECT `main_table`.* FROM `core_website` AS `main_table` ORDER BY main_table.sort_order ASC, main_table.name ASC
46 Query    SELECT `main_table`.* FROM `core_store_group` AS `main_table` ORDER BY main_table.name ASC
46 Query    SELECT `core_url_rewrite`.* FROM `core_url_rewrite` WHERE (request_path IN ('admin', 'admin/')) AND (store_id IN(0, 1))
111207 21:03:07    
46 Query    SELECT `core_translate`.`string`, `core_translate`.`translate` FROM `core_translate` WHERE (store_id IN (0 , '0')) AND (locale = 'en_US') ORDER BY `store_id` ASC
46 Query    SELECT `admin_user`.* FROM `admin_user` WHERE (`admin_user`.`user_id`='1')
46 Query    
46 Quit
```

and here is the PHP error log outout:

> SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1065 Query was
>   empty

```
Trace:
    #0 /home/gyroadmin/www/gyrohobbies.com/lib/Varien/Db/Statement/Pdo/Mysql.php(110): Zend_Db_Statement_Pdo->_execute(Array)
    #1 /home/gyroadmin/www/gyrohobbies.com/lib/Zend/Db/Statement.php(300): Varien_Db_Statement_Pdo_Mysql->_execute(Array)
    #2 /home/gyroadmin/www/gyrohobbies.com/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Abstract.php(479): Zend_Db_Statement->execute(Array)
    #3 /home/gyroadmin/www/gyrohobbies.com/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Abstract.php(238): Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract->query('', Array)
    #4 /home/gyroadmin/www/gyrohobbies.com/lib/Varien/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php(389): Zend_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Abstract->query('', Array)
    #5 /home/gyroadmin/www/gyrohobbies.com/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Abstract.php(753): Varien_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Mysql->query(Object(Varien_Db_Select), Array)
    #6 /home/gyroadmin/www/gyrohobbies.com/app/code/core/Mage/AdminNotification/Model/Resource/Inbox.php(109): Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract->fetchRow(Object(Varien_Db_Select))
    #7 /home/gyroadmin/www/gyrohobbies.com/app/code/core/Mage/AdminNotification/Model/Inbox.php(118): Mage_AdminNotification_Model_Resource_Inbox->parse(Object(Mage_AdminNotification_Model_Inbox), Array)
    #8 /home/gyroadmin/www/gyrohobbies.com/app/code/core/Mage/AdminNotification/Model/Feed.php(97): Mage_AdminNotification_Model_Inbox->parse(Array)
    #9 /home/gyroadmin/www/gyrohobbies.com/app/code/core/Mage/AdminNotification/Model/Observer.php(50): Mage_AdminNotification_Model_Feed->checkUpdate()
    #10 /home/gyroadmin/www/gyrohobbies.com/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(1299): Mage_AdminNotification_Model_Observer->preDispatch(Object(Varien_Event_Observer))
    #11 /home/gyroadmin/www/gyrohobbies.com/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(1280): Mage_Core_Model_App->_callObserverMethod(Object(Mage_AdminNotification_Model_Observer), 'preDispatch', Object(Varien_Event_Observer))
    #12 /home/gyroadmin/www/gyrohobbies.com/app/Mage.php(416): Mage_Core_Model_App->dispatchEvent('controller_acti...', Array)
    #13 /home/gyroadmin/www/gyrohobbies.com/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(505): Mage::dispatchEvent('controller_acti...', Array)
    #14 /home/gyroadmin/www/gyrohobbies.com/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Controller/Action.php(152): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->preDispatch()
    #15 /home/gyroadmin/www/gyrohobbies.com/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(409): Mage_Adminhtml_Controller_Action->preDispatch()
    #16 /home/gyroadmin/www/gyrohobbies.com/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Router/Standard.php(250): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->dispatch('index')
    #17 /home/gyroadmin/www/gyrohobbies.com/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Front.php(176): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Standard->match(Object(Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Http))
    #18 /home/gyroadmin/www/gyrohobbies.com/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(347): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front->dispatch()
    #19 /home/gyroadmin/www/gyrohobbies.com/app/Mage.php(640): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
    #20 /home/gyroadmin/www/gyrohobbies.com/index.php(83): Mage::run('', 'store')
   #21 {main}
```

Comment: Which Magento version are you running?

Answer (score 0):

At first glance this looks to me, like there's something wrong with the resource definitions/tables of your `Mage_AdminNotification` module.

Your system seems to successfully create a proper `Varien_Db_Select` instance, but is not able to read a specific record from the `adminnotification_inbox` table.

Assuming this is the only error occuring: commenting out the `$feedModel->checkUpdate();` call within your `Mage_AdminNotification_Model_Observer` should make you able to reach your  admin backend again, at least.

Comment: [RESOLVED] There was a typo within inbox.php. Thank you both for your replies.